# Use Keras model on dataset of Numpy arrays?

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I am working on a classification project and have a dataset consisting of 2d Numpy arrays (let us call them negative and positive).

I am familiar with Keras classification by simply using the image data generator from directory, but I do not know how to process Numpy arrays.

Please direct me to what the next step should be.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a look at the guidelines for asking a question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You need to provide much more details about what the problem is, including what you have tried so far.

Comment: you can just feed numpy arrays to your NN directly

Comment: When feeding in the numpy arrays to the NN, how do I specify the labels? Is it by array name or are their labels in a separate array?

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is provide the arrays to model.fit. Best way to do that is to build a generator that will supply the data array samples and  label array samples in batches.
I will assume X_array contains your train samples and y_array contains you label samples.
I have not tested it but here is a shot at creating a generator.

```
class data_gen():
    def __init__(self, X_array, y_array, batch_size):
        self.batch_index=0
        self.X_array=X_array
        self.y_array=y_array
        self.batch_size=batch_size         
        self.data_array=np.zeros((self.X_array.shape))
        self.label_array=np.zeros(self.y_array.shape)        
        
    def gen(self):
        length=self.X_array.shape[0] # number of samples
        start=self.batch_index * self.batch_size # set start value of iteration
        end=start + self.batch_size   # set end value of iteration yield 1 batch of data
        for i in range(start, end):
            j=i % length
            self.data_array[j]=(self.X_array[j]) 
            self.label_array[j]=(self.y_array[j])
        self.batch_index=self.batch_index +1
        yield (self.data_array,self.label_array )
```

to test it out try the code below

```
batch_size = 3 #  set what ever batch size you wish
my_gen=data_gen(X_array, y_array, batch_size)
data, labels=next(my_gen.gen())
print (data.shape, labels.shape)
```

you can use my_gen.gen() like you would use ImageDataGenerator.
If you have seperated your data set into train, test and valid data sets using sklearn train_test_split then you can instantiate three generators of the form

```
train_gen=data_gen(X_train, y_train, train_batch_size)
test_gen=data_gen(X_test, y_test, test_baych_size)
valid_gen=data_gen(X_valid, y_valid, valid_batch_size)
```

It would not take to much to modify the generator to read the data from directories in batches so you will not have to load everything into memory and risk an OOM (out of memory) error.  Change the **init** function to have parameters, path to arrays and batch_size. Then in the loop in the gen function read in batch_size number of arrays from the directory to create X_array and y_array. As they used to say in school that is left to the student as an exercise! Good luck